# Can a Slicer be applied to multiple Values?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, slicers

Using Excel 2010.

I'm not even sure how to word this question but here goes:
I have a pivot chart that displays 4 pieces of info by Help desk by Month.

[Screenshot of pivot table fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfDTW.png)

I can add slicers to the resulting chart for the Month Yr and Service Desk but I'm wondering if it's possible to add a slicer for the Values?  The managers may only want to see Calls and Emails in the chart or just see Portal or whatever and I'd hate for them to have to go to the source pivot table and remove the data element from Pivot Table Field List.

[Screenshot of resulting chart (certain proprietary info is purposely cut off)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tR2C.png)

Is this possible and if so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, but it will require some VBA. I've previously written code to do this that you can find at the following link:
[Converting multiple variables into values with excel pivot tables or power pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761634/converting-multiple-variables-into-values-with-excel-pivot-tables-or-power-pivot)