# Pivot Table Issue - Grouping three fields (columns) into one

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have three fields in my pivot table. Each field is connected to one column in my data sheet. [image: Pivot Table]

The goal is to group the 0-30 data (0-30 $ Change),and (0-30 % Change) into one field, and then a slicer with 0-30  as one of the options out of 60-90, 90-120.

Currently I have a combined Pivot Table that looks like this:
[image: Pivot Table Combined]

Again the goal is to make one slicer that would have the 0-30 data as one option in the slicer, the 30-60 data as one option in the slicer and so on...any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: yossup: You've asked a few questions recently but haven't accepted any answers. How 'bout going back through the questions you've asked, and accepting those answers that best address your problem? See stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PIVOT functionality and some formulas my approach would be to concatenate 0-30 data with 0-30 $ Change and 0-30 % Change in one column in the source and then present it in the pivot ROWs area. Here is how it looks wiht some sample data:
[image]

The second image is how the modified source looks like with the formulas used in the top row with yellow ready to be copied down:
[image]

If questions, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to 'switch out' the values fields depending on what someone selects in the Slicer? If so, check out my answer at [Converting multiple variables into values with excel pivot tables or power pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761634/converting-multiple-variables-into-values-with-excel-pivot-tables-or-power-pivot/32812729#32812729)

Basically, youreate a new PivotTable from a data source that contains nothing but the options that you want to show up in the slicer. i.e. '0-30', '30-60' etc. Create a slicer for that PivotTable, and when a user clicks on it, catch the resulting PivotTable_Update event and use it to change which fields shows up in your existing master PivotTable.

See the other thread for more on how to do this.