# Creating Excel Pivot Table to Include Only Rows with Non-Empty Values in Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, pivot, slicers

I'm looking for something very similar to this: [Converting multiple variables into values with excel pivot tables or power pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761634/converting-multiple-variables-into-values-with-excel-pivot-tables-or-power-pivot?answertab=votes#tab-top)

First, I want to say that I've been researching this and trying things for over a week, so my brain may be a little burned out. I could be missing something simple, or what I think should be possible may not be able to be done in Excel.

I think the best way to explain what I need is with a completely different type of situation (i.e. this is not the type of data I'm using, but the situation is the same):

1. Header row: Movie Name | Release Date | Fantasy | Sci Fi | Comedy | Horror
2. First row: Galaxy Quest | 1999 |  | X | X |
3. Second row: Jumanji | 1995 | X |  | X |
4. Third row: The Company of Wolves | 1984 | X |  |  | X
5. Fourth row: Aliens | 1986 |  | X |  | X
6. Fifth row: Spaceballs | 1987 |  | X | X |
7. Sixth row: Willow | 1988 | X |  | X |

I have a pivot table showing, at present, all of the rows of data.

What I need is a slicer that will show 1) all comedy, no matter the other choices; or 2) all comedy and fantasy, which would show Galaxy Quest (comedy), Jumanji (comedy and fantasy), The Company of Wolves (fantasy), Spaceballs (comedy), Willow (comedy and fantasy); etc.

I hope the question makes sense. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Sounds like you need to normalise your data so that 'genre' is a single column, which you can then use as a Slicer field.

Comment: Unfortunately, not able to do that.

Comment: Why not? Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: The reason is that the data I'm actually using this for has to do with meetings, and a meeting is never just for one topic.

Comment: You still want to normalise your data. I would unpivot the columns using Power Query, into one column which I could then multi-select in a slicer. You don't say which version of Excel you are using, so I do not know if a Power Query solution will work for you.

Comment: Excel 2013, and I have no experience with Power Query. I have more experience with VBA, but am willing to work with anything that lets the bosses see the data that they want to see.

I have created a data entry form for them to use, and they only want to do one for each meeting.  Any way that I can combine "types" into one column would be helpful, but I just can't wrap my brain around it. (I would chat, but SO won't let me.... sorry for the long discussion in comments.)