# Add column to Excel Power Pivot Table based on slicer seection

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot

I have an Excel Power Pivot Data Model with one table of about 3m entries. In one of my sheets I have multiple slicers that I combine to select entries that fit specific criteria.

I would like to add a column with a value that comes from a cell in the sheet, but only when the entry was part of the selection. For example: when the value in the cell is 1, the selected entries will get "1" in the added column. After that the number in the cell could be set to 2 and a new selection could be made. The new selection will all have "2" in the same added column.

I have been trying to make this work running a macro and DAX, but it can't get it to work. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: We can't answer your question without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VBA I've previously posted at [Converting multiple variables into values with excel pivot tables or power pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761634/converting-multiple-variables-into-values-with-excel-pivot-tables-or-power-pivot) to do that. It requires you to make up a 'harvester' PivotTable containing just the columns you want to swap out, so that you can then create a slicer from which to trigger the code.

You can also write a conditional formula in DAX that uses a harvester measure. Something like https://powerpivotpro.com/2012/11/one-slicer-to-control-them-all/ (and plenty of other examples on Google)